# Get a udev symlink registered as a serial in softwares

Tags: usb, udev, symbolic-link, serial-port

I created udev rules to have specific symlinks to my USB device.

The USB device is a serial device that usually comes up as ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1. I made the symlink to be sure I have always the same reference to the device between each reboot.

This is my udev rule below.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523", SYMLINK+="ttyFEEDERS"
```

This works. However all software that I use do not see this symlink as a serial port and do not list it as option to open. For example Cutecom does not offer my symlink to open and it is the same with all other software using a serial port.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Hello. I do not see any mention of Ubuntu version in your question.

Comment: 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)